# Why is the total sum of the list incorrect?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am solving project Euler's exercise 1:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9.  The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the
>   sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I been stuck on this for a while and after doing some research this is how to calculate the sum.

```
# range of numbers 0 to 1000
# iterate through numbers
for number in range(1001):
    multiples = []    
    # multiples of 3 or 5
    if (number % 3 == 0) or (number % 5 == 0):
        # store num into array
        multiples.append(number)

# add up all elements in array
total = sum(multiples)
print total
```

My output is 1000

UPDATE: I just read on project euler not to post the solution online. I guess my question is pretty close to the solution. If the moderators think it should be deleted, then please do so.

Comment: Take `multiples` outside the loop.

Comment: Reading this should help: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `multiples` is set to a empty list inside the loop.

```
multiples = []  # <----------
for number in range(1001):
    if (number % 3 == 0) or (number % 5 == 0):
        multiples.append(number)
```

Comment: i see now. the list being inside the loop made it reset everytime?

Comment: @Beast_Code, Yes it does.